# How to create a Connection Pool in Web App rather than in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jndi, connection-pooling

I want to create a **connection pool** for my Oracle database but I want this connection pool to be created when my Web App is deployed in my Tomcat Server.

What I 've seen until now is loads of examples on how to create connection pooling in tomcat using **JNDI** and by defining the resource in the `context.xml`. That means (If I got this right) that even id you undeploy your app the pool remains in the server with open connections.

Is there any way to define the connection pool in the Web App rather than in tomcat server?

Thanks

Comment: You could you add your own ServletContextListener (google it) to initiate it, inside your web app, when it starts. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) to manage connections at application level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define the pool as a static class member.  Initialize it in a static constructor and use factory methods to get connections from it.